# nth-of-type doesn't work on div

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm having 3 divs, all with class `thirtytwo`, and I'm trying to style them using `nth-of-type` like this:

`.thirtytwo:nth-of-type(1){ style.. }`

But for some reason, nothing happens, anyone has any idea what it might be ?

Comment: maybe let us really see ur code sire? or make a fiddle or something..

Comment: We'll needmore information. Please make jsfindle or something. It could come from your css link file, an class overiding or a lot of other little css problems.

Comment: `.thirtytwo{
    width: 32%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}

.thirtytwo:nth-of-type(1){
    margin-right: 2%!important;
}
.thirtytwo:nth-of-type(2){
    margin-right: 2%!important;
}
.thirtytwo:nth-of-type(3){
    margin-right: 0%!important;
} `    and here is the html  ` <div class="thirtytwo">
    <span class="three-about-text">content
    </span>
</div><div class="thirtytwo">
    <span class="three-about-text">content
    </span>
</div>
<div class="clear_all"></div>`

Comment: pls edit your question and add your HTML code too!

Comment: I have added just 2 of the 3 divs because of the char limit , there are 3 thirtytwo divs..

Comment: there is currently error with this code you have. probably its the whole file's code issue. like you left some element unclosed or open. pls check, or if you could. show us your file.

Comment: that's the strange thing.. my code looks all right.. and I've just controlled , all the elements are closed

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

```
Your code works fine.
```

```css
.thirtytwo{ 
  width: 32%; 
  float: left; 
  text-align: center; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  padding: 10px; 
  border:1px solid;
} 
.thirtytwo:nth-of-type(1){ 
  margin-right: 2%!important; 
} 
.thirtytwo:nth-of-type(2){ 
  margin-right: 2%!important; 
} 
.thirtytwo:nth-of-type(3){ 
  margin-right: 0%!important; 
}
```

```html
<div class="thirtytwo">DIV1</div>
<div class="thirtytwo">DIV2</div>
<div class="thirtytwo">DIV3</div>
```

maybe try checking your elements cause maybe you left one element unclosed or open above your 3 divs.

Comment: i cant think of any other possible mistake. maybe, javascripts, or idk